Let $O$ be a topology on $M$, $f: M \rightarrow M$ be a continuous bijection on $O$. Is $f^{-1}$ continuous?
I'm just learning about topologies. This seems to be something that should intuitively be true, but I'm having a really hard (nearly impossible) time proving it. I also can't think of counterexamples off the top of my head, as this works for the standard topology of $R^n$ (open sets) and seems to work for trivial examples.
If we assume one (let's say $f$) is continuous, and we let $Q \in O$, then $f^{-1}(Q) \in O$ as it's the pre image and thus $f^{-n}(Q) \in O$ for any natural $n$. Great. But there's nothing inherently saying $f(Q) \in O$. $O$ cannot be the power set because $f(Q) \subset M$. Thus, let's assume it's not. I'm 99% sure that this would mean there exists a set $P$ s.t. $P=\{x\}, x \in M, $ and $P \notin O$ because otherwise, $O$ would just be the power set and contain $f(Q)$, as you could just take unions with the sets with one element to get the power set anyways. Naturally, this means $\forall n \in N, f^{n}(P) \notin O$, and for that matter, $f^n(f(Q)) \notin O$. This still doesn't give us any contradiction, and it seems the only way to reach a contradiction would be to use the fact that f is bijective to somehow invalidate the assumptions of $O$ being a topology......but the requirements for a topology are so broad that it seems hard to really say anything about the problem. We only know that $f^{-n}(Q)$ are in the topology, but there's nothing saying their intersections or unions have to result in one of the $f^n(P)$s or $f^n(f(Q))$s.

Not true. Try searching for an answer on the net or on this site.

The usual counterexample is $e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$.

@AlexOrtiz I'm curious as to how you consider $\theta \mapsto e^{i \theta}$ as a function with codomain $[0, 2\pi)$.

I misread the question---my comment only addresses continuous bijections

Let $C_i$ be circles and $L_i=[0,1)$ for $i\in \mathbb N.$ Let $M$ be the disjoint union. Send $L_0\to C_0$ by $x\mapsto e^{2\pi i x},$ and otherwise  $L_{i+1}\to L_i$ and $C_i\to C_{i+1}$ be identities. This is an example inspired by @AlexOrtiz's (incorrect) example.

In general, you won't find an example with $M$ compact and Hausdorff, because a continuous bijection $X\to Y$ with $X$ compact and $Y$ Hausdorff is always a homeomorphism.

My example of the circles and half-open segments is non-compact, but Hausdorff. It would be interesting to find a compact but not Hausdorff example.

That map is not a bijection. @geetha290krm It is not onto.

Let $\ell_0$ be the space of  finitely supported sequences of real numbers with the sup norm. Define $f(x_i))=(x_i/i)$. This is a continuous bijection but its inverse is not continuous. I am not posting an answer because these basic questions about continuity of the inverse have been discussed long back on MSE.

@ThomasAndrews Thanks for pointing out. Please check my new example. This can also be written in  terms of polynomials, if you wish.

@GeorgeCoote This is true for $M$ being an open subset of any Euclidean space (in particular $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$). See invariance of domain.

@ThomasAndrews I’ve added an answer providing a compact $T_1$ example.

@DavidGao TIL! thanks

Thanks for all of the answers and for providing examples and being patient at least. While you say that there are many answers, I seem to be bad at finding / searching for them, perhaps this has to do with wording the question. But thanks anyways.

While both Thomas Andrews and geetha290krm have provided counterexamples in comments, and while there are likely plenty more counterexamples that can be found on this site and/or the rest of Internet, I’m writing an answer mostly to address Thomas’s question in comments, namely, whether a counterexample exists in which $M$ is compact. As Thomas already observed, $M$ being compact Hausdorff will imply any continuous bijection $f: M \to M$ is a homeomorphism. The compactness assumption is necessary as both Thomas and geetha290krm’s counterexamples are Hausdorff. I’ll show the Hausdorff condition is also necessary by demonstrating a compact example - in fact, a compact $T_1$ example.
Let $M = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ (where we shall consider $0 \in \mathbb{N}$) be equipped with the topology with the following basis,
$$\mathcal{B} = \{[\mathbb{N} \times ([n, \infty) \cap \mathbb{N})] \setminus F: n \in \mathbb{N}, F \subset \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \text{ is finite}\}$$
It is straightforward to check that this topology is compact and that, because all co-finite subsets are open in this topology, it is $T_1$. Now, fix a bijection $\sigma = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2): \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \{0, 1\}$. Define $g: M \to M$,
$$g(m, n) = (\sigma_1(m), 2n + \sigma_2(m))$$
It is not hard to check that this is a bijection. Thus, we may let $f = g^{-1}$. One may readily verify that $g$ is open, so $f$ is a continuous bijection. But $g = f^{-1}$ is not continuous, as, for example, $g^{-1}(\mathbb{N} \times ([1, \infty) \cap \mathbb{N}))$ cannot be open - its intersection with $\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}$ will be infinite but not co-finite (in $\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}$), but, as can be easily checked, the intersection of any open set with $\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}$ is either empty or co-finite in $\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}$.
